# How to display urls of a custom component on breadcrumbs?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, breadcrumbs

I need to display links of a custom component on breadcrumbs. How can i get it done?

Example my component (site part) has the following url:

`site.com/gallery/animals/` where `animals` is the URL of the component and `gallery` is the menu item alias

My breadcrumb shows:

`home/gallery` instead of `home/gallery/animals`

UPDATE

The "problem" lies in `modules/mod_breadcrumbs/helper` specifically in the `getPathWay()` method; It returns the path but not including the url of the component. The `print_r` function gave me:

`Joomla\CMS\Pathway\SitePathway Object ( [_pathway:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Gallery [link] => index.php?option=com_galley&view=gallery&Itemid=361 ) ) [_count:protected] => 1 )` where `index.php?option=com_galley&view=gallery&Itemid=361` is the url of the menu item; it should have given me (i expected it at least) something like this:

`Joomla\CMS\Pathway\SitePathway Object ( [_pathway:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Gallery [link] => index.php?option=com_galley&view=galler&Itemid=361 ) [link] => &view=gallery&Itemid=91 ) ) [_count:protected] => 1 )` where `&view=gallery&Itemid=91` would be my component url.

Is there any way to add the url of custom component to the `getPathWay()` method?

UPDATE

I found a method to add an item to the pathway; the method is `addItem(string $name, string $link)`

Something like this:

```
$app= JFactory::()->getApplication();
$pathway=$app->getPathWay();
$pathway->addItem('Animals' , 'animals');
```

it works but now i need a way to automatically get it from the URL and add it to the method `addItem()`

Comment: I was actually realising that the URL of a custom component (site part) didn't appear on breadcrumbs. I will probably have to override the breadcrumbs and make some modifications. I haven't tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a function to your `view.html.php` file of your component

The function will:

1. Get url parameters
2. Retrieve the name/title of the current page from the database and add a new item to the path with the `addItem()` method.

The function:

```
        /* 
        Function to add a new item to the breadcrumbs.
        The function name can be whatever you want
        */
        function addNewItemBreadcrumb(){

           //it will initialize the variable input in order to get the url parameters
           $input= JFactory::getApplication()->input;

           /* get the id parameter from the url, even if your url is a friendly url. Example: 
           site.com/index.php?com_yourcomponent?&view=article&id=37&Itemid=103 or site.com/article the below code will get the id
           parameter which is 37 */ 

          //get the id of the page. We will use this to retrieve the name of the article from the database

           $id=$input->get('id');

           //here we will retrieve the name of the article from the database

           $db=JFactory::getDbo();
           $q=$db->getQuery(true);
           $q->select('name_of_the_column_you_want_to_display');
           $q->from('#__yourcomponent_yourtable')
           $q->where('id='.$db->quote($id));
           $name=$db->setQuery(true);
           $name=$db->loadResult();


          //add a new item to the breadcrumbs

          $app=JFactory::getApplication();
          $pathway=$app->getPathWay();

          //this will add a new breadcrumb item with the name of the article we got from the database

          return $pathway->addItem($name);  

         /* if you also want to add a link you can do the following:
         return $pathway->addItem($name, JRoute::_('index.php?option=your_component&view=your_view&id='.$id));  
          */


 }
```

Now just call the function in your `view.html.php`

```
$this->addNewItemBreadcrumb();
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify `mod_breadcrumbs`. You can add pathway items in your component's views.

Comment: Yes i have tried and it's worked out. Thank you.

Comment: @Sharky your solution is even better because we no longer need to verify the component's name nor the view's name.

Comment: You also probably don't need to make database queries. Normally the item should already be available at this point.

Comment: @Sharky indeed it works, however I tried adding a new pathitem to the `setDocument` function and it  displayed like two empty items.

Comment: @Sharky nevermind, i just had an extra function call in my view.